# Extract labels that repeats with different values using regex on notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I trying to extract strings which repeat through the text, with same labels but different values after =. For example, a would like to isolate Name item (bolded in text), then information about YearsToPith and Radius from the following text:

```
00010131 DistanceToPith=15.0; YearsToPith=3; Radius=50.128; CalcRadius=Yes; 
00010131 PithCoordinates=60.919,6.071; SiteId=KO31; 
00010131 Location=Djerdap, GJ "Kožica" odeljenje 31; State=Srbija; 
00010131 SpeciesCode=QUPE; SpeciesName=Kitnjak, Quercus petrea; 
00010131 Personal_ID=Marko Kazimirovic; DateOfSampling=jesen 2013; 
00010131 Name=00010131; Written=2018-05-04 16:53:09; 
00010131 EarthCoord=E 44 35 N 21 58; Elev=450-465; 
00010131 Project=Radakovicev magistarski; 
00010132 DistanceToPith=6.7; YearsToPith=3; Radius=104.927; CalcRadius=Yes; 
00010132 PithCoordinates=108.974,27.022; Written=2018-05-04 17:09:35; 
00010132 SiteId=KO31; Location=Djerdap, GJ "Kožica" odeljenje 31; 
00010132 EarthCoord=E 44 35 N 21 58; Elev=450-465; State=Srbija; 
00010132 SpeciesCode=QUPE; SpeciesName=Kitnjak, Quercus petrea; 
00010132 Project=Radakovicev magistarski; Personal_ID=Marko Kazimirovic;
00010132 DateOfSampling=jesen 2013; Name=00010132;
```

It doesn't matter if extracted mentioned items separately or all together. My best was to locate information with:

```
 (Name)+[=]+[19\d]+[;]
```

but didn't catch how to delete the text before and after.

Comment: Try `.*?(Name=\d+;).*\R*|.*\R*` and replace with `$1`. This will remove lines that have no pattern like the one you have and will keep the first occurrence of this pattern on a line that contains the match.

Comment: Perfect, just what I looking for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

**Find What**: `.*?(Name=\d+;).*\R*|.*\R*`
**Replace With**: `$1`

This will remove lines that have no pattern like the one you have and will keep the first occurrence of this pattern on a line that contains the match.

**Details**

- `.*?(Name=\d+;).*\R*`:

  - `.*?` - 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
  - `(Name=\d+;)` - Group 1: `Name=` and 1+ digits and then `;`
  - `.*` - 0+ chars other than line break chars
  - `\R*` - 0+ line break sequences
- `|` - or
- `.*\R*` - 0+ chars other than line break chars followed with 0+ line break sequences.